# Can't delete music from iOS device in iTunes

Tags: itunes

When I connect my iPod or iPhone to iTunes on a MacBook Pro, it will look like this picture attached. When I right-click on a song to delete it, there is no delete option. What am I doing wrong? This new iTunes has been so confusing.

[image]

Comment: also if I go to its GetInfo section, everything is read-only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is likely because iTunes is automatically syncing your music.

[image: iTunes sync music]

When you automatically sync music, you manage what songs you have on your device by going to the music tab, and selecting which playlists/artists/genres/albums to sync or not sync.

### The fix:

To manually manage music, click the Summary tab, scroll to close to the bottom, and in the Options area, there will be an option to Manually manage music and videos. Select this option, and you should be able to delete songs and such from the "On this iPhone" tab.

[image]

Comment: I hadn't selected Sync music option but somehow the other thing to Manually Manage Music, that one worked. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, thanks for the feedback. I'll edit my post to make the Manually Manage music a little clearer for future visitors.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clue about manual manage. It was driving me insane!

Comment: For iTunes on **Windows**, Summary is in the navbar on the left - AFTER you click on the tiny little iPhone icon below the menu.

Answer (score 2):

This is on a different computer to mine. I knew to enable "manually manage" etc. however itunes wants to sync to the library on the new computer erasing all my music before I can apply the manaul management of my iphone library. Really annoying not to mention I don't want the phone backing up all the time, sync maybe but not backup too. Also the change of layout was confusing. why did it have to change the old way worked.