# iTunes 11 won't allow iPod content delete

Tags: itunes, ipod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t delete music from iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74952/cant-delete-music-from-itunes)

My wife has a Windows laptop (I know) and since installing iTunes 11, she can't access the content on her iPod (click wheel) when it's connected. iTunes reads the iPod, but will not allow her to add or delete. How can she delete content from her iPod to make room for new?